# Using Svg Paths to render Svg

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

Is it possible to render svg from svg paths?

Like in JavaScript, we are having Path2D to render svg paths to canvas. Similarly, Is there any way to render a svg path to the QGraphicsScene?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [QGraphicsSvgItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicssvgitem.html) to put an SVG onto a QGraphicsScene. It

- can be constructed directly from an SVG-file
- allows to restrict rendering to a certain ID within the SVG-data (if you only want to render a small subset of a large file)
- can connect to a [QSvgRenderer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsvgrenderer.html)

The last option is useful if you have no file but rather raw SVG-data in a buffer, i.e. received via a network connection or created dynamically from user input.